# How to control 6v micro solenoid from arduino

Tags: control, motor

I want to control [this](https://www.fabtolab.com/solenoid-electromagnet-micro-5v) solenoid from Arduino, but I am confused which transistors, resistors and diodes to choose. I have seen a lot of tutorials about controlling solenoid from Arduino, but all of them are for 12 volt solenoid or are using some relays which I don't want to use. I will be using 6 of these solenoids for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Most of 12V solenoid tutorials would work here too, if you use just 6V instead of 12V. Post here links to some 12V tutorial, I will look at that and say you, if they are easy to adjust and how.

Or as last resort - your selenoid is rated 6V/0.35A - that is 17.14 Ohm, you can buy power resistor 17-20 Ohm with minimal of 7 Watt (can be much more Watt, no problem - probably big ceramic one) and just connet it in serie with your solenoid and then follow ANY 12V solenoid tutorial verbatim (with this combination in place for 12V solenoid - as it is de-facto 12V / 0.35A solenoid together)

Comment: this is one tutorial: http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-solenoids-with-arduino/  , i already have got 2n2222 npn transistor, 1kohm resistor, .1micro farad capacitor and 1n4001 diode, can i use them. i was using them for 3 volt vibration motor before this.

Comment: If it worked for your 3V motor and should work for 12V solenoid (as in tutorial), it would work for 6V solenoid too, just use 6V power sourse for the solenoid. As per datasheet of 2N2222 it should be able take 0.8A max, your soleonid wants only 0.35A, so it is OK too. If you are to use 6 solenoids, you will need 6 transistors, 6 diodes, 6 resistors (one set for each solenoid) regardless if you want to drive them with one pin or 6 different pins. Also your 6V power source should be able deliver 6x0.35A=2.1A minimal (rather more, does not hurt to NOT go extreme).

Comment: You can use one common 6V source of 2.1A or 6 independent sources per 0.35A (one per solenoid), as you wish. (If it works, please select this as an answer and upvote it)